# How do I loop this function in python?

Tags: python, api

I am trying to extract hours of operations of a list of restaurants hitting Yelp API after I retrieved their respective business id:

My original defined function was:

```
def is_clocked(business_id):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    try:
        clocked_ind = get_business(API_KEY, business_id)
        clocked_ind1 = clocked_ind['hours']
    except:
        clocked_ind1 = 'None'
    return clocked_ind1
clocked_ind = is_clocked(b_id)
print(clocked_ind)
```

However, this function returned to me a long data instead of wide data format:

bad_format:

```
Querying https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/9GzjKeifGJ6KzWkaPftYHg ...
[{'open': [{'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 0}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 1}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 2}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 3}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 4}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 5}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2100', 'day': 6}], 'hours_type': 'REGULAR', 'is_open_now': True}]
```

I want my final output to look like this in a csv:

(input)

```
day = [0, 1,2,3,4,5,6]
start = [1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100]
end = [2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2200, 2100]
day1 = []
for i in day:
    day1.append("start"+str(i))

for i in range(len(day1)):
        merge_HOO[day1[i]]=start[i]

pd.DataFrame(merge_HOO, index=[0])

#Desired Output[115]: 
   item  day start   end  end0   ...    start2  start3  start4  start5  start6
0     0    0  1100  2200  2200   ...      1100    1100    1100    1100    1100
```

But as you notice: I manually coded the input for once particular business. I want to create a loop such that it returns in csv my desired output for each business_id. I have also written the code below, but i feel there has to be a better way to make this loop. The below code needs to be a a function:

```
day = day_open(b_id)
start = day_start(b_id)
end = day_end(b_id)
day1 = []
for i in day:
    day1.append("start"+str(i))
dict1 = {}
for i in range(len(day1)):
        dict1[day1[i]]=start[i]
start_df = pd.DataFrame(dict1, index=[0])


day2 = []
for i in day:
    day2.append("end"+str(i))
dict2 = {}
for i in range(len(day2)):
        dict2[day2[i]]=end[i]
end_df = pd.DataFrame(dict2, index=[0])
start_df['end0']=end_df['end0']
start_df['end0']=end_df['end0']
start_df['end0']=end_df['end0']
start_df['end0']=end_df['end0']
start_df['end0']=end_df['end0']
start_df['end0']=end_df['end0']
```

I want to fit this in a loop similarly as below:

```
def id_loop(a):
    empty = []
    for i in input_range:
        review_count_ind = is_review_count(a[i])
        empty.append(review_count_ind)
    return empty

c = id_loop(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

your expected output is inconsistent with your data. is `item` the same thing as `is_overnight`? you have `end` and `end0`, what does this mean? so i assumed that `item` is `is_overnight` and that all column names should be appended with the day number. as your result is a list i also assumed that its length could change.

```
import pandas as pd

clocked_ind = [{'open': [{'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 0}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 1}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 2}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 3}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 4}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2200', 'day': 5}, {'is_overnight': False, 'start': '1100', 'end': '2100', 'day': 6}], 'hours_type': 'REGULAR', 'is_open_now': True}]

new_list = [[] for _ in range(len(clocked_ind)+1)]
for i in range(len(clocked_ind)):
    new_list[i+1] = []
    for day_dict in clocked_ind[i]['open']:
        suffix = str(day_dict['day'])
        for k, v in day_dict.items():
            key = k if k != 'is_overnight' else 'item'
            column_name = key + suffix
            if column_name not in new_list[0]:
                new_list[0].append(column_name)
            new_list[i+1].append(v)  # if you want item to store int instead of bool replace with append(int(v))

df  = pd.DataFrame(new_list[1:], columns=new_list[0])
print(df)
```

output

```
   item0  day0  end0 start0  item1  day1  end1 start1  item2  day2  ...    \
0  False     0  2200   1100  False     1  2200   1100  False     2  ...     

   end4 start4  item5  day5  end5 start5  item6  day6  end6 start6  
0  2200   1100  False     5  2200   1100  False     6  2100   1100  

[1 rows x 28 columns]
```

Comment: I did not want overnight to feature in my output and I have already reached this stage. but I want to include this in the loop. @bobrobbob

Comment: the desired output you gave is wrong so no, you haven't reach this stage. what loop are you talking about and what is your really desired output then?

Comment: for i in my_list[0]["open"]:
    del i["is_overnight"]

print(my_list) I removed overnight from my output already